# PageRenderer does not work with camera2 API

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-camera

I am trying to get Camera2 API to work from Xamarin Forms through Page Rendering.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CameraPage), typeof(CameraActivity))]
namespace BlueDemo.Droid
{
     [Activity(Label = "CameraActivity")]
     public class CameraActivity : PageRenderer
{
        Activity activity;
        TextureView textureView;
        global::Android.Views.View view;

    public CameraActivity(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Page> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.OldElement != null || Element == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            SetupUserInterface();
            AddView(view);


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(@"           ERROR: ", ex.Message);
        }
    }
    void SetupUserInterface()
    {
        //activity = Context as Activity;
        view = activity.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.activity_camera, this, false);
        activity.FragmentManager.BeginTransaction().Replace(Resource.Id.container, Camera2BasicFragment.NewInstance()).Commit();

    }
```

The break point does hit the LayoutInflater but it does not open the view for the camera. The original Camera2 API: [Camera2 API link for camera activity](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/master/android5.0/Camera2Basic/Camera2Basic/CameraActivity.cs)

This has SetContentView which does not work with Page Renderer.

Comment: It is working. There is no issue in the class

Comment: It shows blank screen for me.